# Parse.Cloud.run slow on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have some code that runs a parse cloud function, then processes the results. This uses their javascript api (1.3.0), and is running in an ionic framework app. When running on a mac in chrome browser the response normally takes around 500ms. The exact same code running on iOS seems to differ quite wildly. Its always much slower, and can take anywhere from 3 to 20 seconds. Both iOS and mac are on the same wireless network. Why is it so much slower, and how can I speed it up?

```
var start = Date.now();
console.log("PARSE CLOUD RUN");            
Parse.Cloud.run('getFixtures', {teamID : teamID, divisionID : divisionIDs}, {
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("PARSE CLOUD SUCCESS :" + (Date.now() - start));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to handle this situation. Parse query has a built-in support for caching that makes it a lot easier to save query results on disk. In case there is no network access, your app can load the result from cache. Caching also improves the app performance. Instead of loading data from Parse every time when the app runs, it retrieves the data from cache on startup.

By default, caching is disabled. But it can be easily enabled using a single line of code. Add the following code in queryForTable: method (after the initialization of PFquery):

```
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
```

The Parse query supports various types of cache policy. The `kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork` policy is just one of them. It first loads data from the cache, then from the network.